# About definite integral and Gauss hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I feel very shameful asking questions on this forum, but while solving complex mathematical papers, sometimes I just cannot understand how the authors have proceeded. :(

Not sure if this is the case with everyone or is it just me

$$G(\theta) = 1+d\cos(n\theta)$$

$$\boxed{I = \int^{2\pi}_0 G(\theta)^{2/n} d\theta}$$

Authors claim that this integral can be simplified to:

$$= \pi\Big[
(1-d)^{2/n}{_2F_1}\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{2}{n},1,\frac{2d}{d-1}\Big)+
(1+d)^{2/n}{_2F_1}\Big(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{2}{n},1,\frac{2d}{d+1}\Big)\Big] $$

$$= 2\pi - \frac{\pi(n-2)}{n}d^2 + \mathcal{O}(d^4)$$

where ${_2F_1}$ is the Gaussian hypergeometric function.

I have no idea where this come from. I looked at the book thoroughly : "Table of integrals, series, and products / I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik ; Daniel Zwillinger" but could not find.

PS. There are some other details later, which I am unable to grasp fully. Also I can't find how $\mathcal{O}(.)$ comes from. Please find the figure attached.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $|d|<1$, you can write $(1 + d \cos(n\theta))^{2/n}$ as a binomial series
$$ (1+d \cos(n\theta)^{2/n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {2/n \choose k} (d\cos(n\theta))^k$$
and integrate term-by-term.  Assuming $n$ is a nonzero integer,

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(n\theta)^k \; d\theta = \cases{0 & if $k$ is odd\cr 
                                         {k \choose k/2} 2^{1-k} \pi & if $k$ is even}$$
and then your integral becomes
$$ \sum_{j=0}^\infty {2/n \choose 2j} {2j \choose j} 2^{1-2j} \pi d^{2j} = 2\,\pi\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(-1/n,(n-2)/(2n);\,1;\,{d}^{2})}
$$

I don't know where the other hypergeometric expression comes from, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any comment on the $\mathcal{O}(d^4}$ i.e. Big-O notation here?

Comment: I have actually two objections. First that since $n\geq2$, we $2/n$ is not always an integer quantity. But, may be for simplifications authors in the paper ignore this fact. Second, $d>0$, and it can even be $>1$ as well :(

Comment: I want $n$ to be an integer, not $2/n$.

Comment: If $d > 1$, $1 + d \cos(n\theta)$ can be negative, and that will give your integral an imaginary component when $n$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why only divisible by 4? The argument of the integrand is either $0$ or $2 \pi/n$, the imaginary part doesn't cancel out when $d > 1 \land n > 2$. For $0 < d < 1$, your result extends to real $n$, because the integral and ${_2F_1}$ are analytic at infinity.

Comment: If $n$ is not divisible by $4$, $z^{2/n}$ where $z$ is negative has a real branch.  The question did not specify which branch to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it would be shameful to ask for a clarification, especially since the series expansion in (13) appears to contain a mistake. I'll use the closed form given by Robert Israel. The coefficient at $d^2$ in the expansion around $d = 0$ is 
$$\frac
 {2 \pi \left( -\frac 1 \eta \right)_{\hspace{-2px}1}
  \left( \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 \eta\right)_{\hspace{-2px}1}}
 {(1)_1} =
\frac {\pi (2 - \eta)} {\eta^2}.$$
For $d = 1$, Gauss's theorem gives
$$2 \pi \,{_2F_1} \!\left( -\frac 1 \eta, \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 \eta; 1; 1 \right) =
\frac
 {2 \pi \Gamma(1) \Gamma \!\left( \frac 1 2 + \frac 2 \eta \right)}
 {\Gamma \!\left( \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 \eta \right)
  \Gamma \!\left( 1 + \frac 1 \eta \right)},$$
and (14) is the expansion around $\eta = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What does $\mathcal{O}(d^4)$ mean here and how can I solve this thing numerically (I mean on Matlab)

Comment: It's the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The argument of ${_2F_1}$ is $d^2$, the next term in the Taylor expansion is of order $d^4$. I'm not sure whether you want to compute the integral or something else numerically.